# Effectively passing variables from a model then into the session

Tags: codeigniter, session-variables

I am new to code igniter and MVC PHP, I have created a basic login system with online resources and it works, I am now trying to improve it to learn ...

my model:

```
function validate(){


            $this->db->where('Email', $this->input->post('email'));
            $this->db->where('Password', sha1($this->input->post('password')));
            $query = $this->db->get('admin_users');

        if($query->num_rows == 1){

            return true;
        }

    }

    function get_admininfo(){


        $this->db->where('Email', $this->session->userdata('email'));
        $query = $this->db->get('admin_users');

        return $query->result();
    }
```

One a user has validated I want to pull some of their information and store it in the session, for notifications and such, avatars.

My Controller looks like this:

```
 function validate_credentials(){

        //load the adminship model and then the function validate within it.
        $this->load->model('adminship_model');
        $query = $this->adminship_model->validate();

        // If the admin user successfully validated.
        if($query){

            $admininfo = $this ->adminship_model->get_admininfo();

            $data = array(

                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'username' => $this->$admininfo['username'],
                'is_logged_in' => true
            );

            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect('dashboard_controller/dashboard');


        }else{

           $this->index();

        }

    }
```

In the dashboard controller I set:

```
        $data['email'] = $this->session->userdata('email');
        $data['email'] = $this->session->userdata('username');
```

And pass it to the view, and when i echo $email I get the email, but the username doesnt pull I get this error:

Message: Undefined index: username

This line:

```
'username' => $this->$admininfo['username'],
```

I know I'm pulling the info in the wrong way from the model, can someone point me into the right direction please.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your model function to:

```
 function get_admininfo(){
    $this->db->where('Email', $this->session->userdata('email'));
    $query = $this->db->get('admin_users');

    if($query->num_rows() == 1){
       foreach($query->result() as $row){
            $data = $row;
       }
       return $data;

    } else {
    return FALSE;
    }
 }
```

and then try to get the data in this way:

```
   $admininfo = $this ->adminship_model->get_admininfo();
        $data = array(

            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'username' => $admininfo->username,
            'is_logged_in' => true
        );
```

**EDIT**

Try go get `all_userdata()` since you are going to use it:

`$data['userdata'] = $this->session->all_userdata(); // returns an associative array`

Then pass that to the view and get it out in the view with `$userdata['username']`, This usually works fine for me.

**OPTION**

If the code above doesn't work, probably the easiest way would be to specify name of the column like:

```
function get_admininfo(){
    $this->db->where('Email', $this->session->userdata('email'));
    $query = $this->db->get('admin_users');

    if($query->num_rows() == 1){
        $row = $query->row(); 
        return $row->username; //assuming this is the name of the column
    } else {
    return FALSE;
    }
 }
```

Change the controller code to:

```
        $admininfo = $this ->adminship_model->get_admininfo();
        $data = array(

            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'username' => $admininfo,
            'is_logged_in' => true
        );
```

Comment: I do this, then when I want to display it : $data['username'] = $this->session->userdata('username'); and in the view: <?php echo $username; ?>. However I get this error: Message: Object of class __PHP_Incomplete_Class could not be converted to string

Answer (score 0):

the function

```
function get_admininfo(){


    $this->db->where('Email', $this->session->userdata('email'));
    $query = $this->db->get('admin_users');

    return $query->result();
}
```

is trying to return the query as an object

and

```
      $admininfo = $this ->adminship_model->get_admininfo();

        $data = array(

            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'username' => $this->$admininfo['username'],
            'is_logged_in' => true
        );
```

is trying to set $data['username'] to an expected array value from $this->admininfo but it returned an object

try changing:

```
return $query->result();
```

to

```
return $query->row_array();
```

Comment: also I wanted to mention that after you get comfortable in codeigniter go checkout this mashup of two libraries from jamie rumbelow: https://github.com/williamknauss/schema_base_model_magic. it allows for much easier CRUD model creation and it helps implement "dont repeat yourself" patterns.